# Who were the ghosts that appeared alongside Diva?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

In the 2017 theatrical film *[Yu-Gi-Oh!: The Dark Side of Dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!:_The_Dark_Side_of_Dimensions)*, Diva at several points starts using the power of the plana and a side effect of this is that a number of ghosts appear around him.

[image: Yu-Gi-Oh!: The Dark Side of Dimensions ghosts]
<sub>You don't stand a *ghost* of a chance!</sub>

Were these other children who were trained by Shadi? If so, why do we see so few of them in the flashbacks?

Or are these the remnants of those who were sent to the Shadow Realm (or whatever) by Diva, as we saw with the bullies near the beginning of the film?